# ASP.NET MaskedEditExtender теряется маска после отправки на сервер.

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Здравствуйте!
У меня такая проблема. На странице к TextBox привязаны MaskedEditExtender и MaskedEditValidator:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="WeekendsS3Time2" runat="server" Text="Время" OnFocus="this.select()"           CssClass="route" Width="40" Tag="лето;выходные" />
<cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="WeekendsS3Time2_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="true" ClearTextOnInvalid="true"                                       Enabled="True" TargetControlID="WeekendsS3Time2" MaskType="Time" Mask="99:99" CultureName="ru-RU">
</cc1:MaskedEditExtender>
<cc1:MaskedEditValidator ID="WeekendsS3Time2_MaskedEditValidator" runat="server"                                                ControlExtender="WeekendsS3Time2_MaskedEditExtender" InvalidValueMessage="Некорректно введена дата!" ForeColor="Red"                                            ControlToValidate="WeekendsS3Time2" IsValidEmpty="true" MaximumValue="23:59" MinimumValue="00:00"ToolTip="Введите время в промежутке от 00:00 до 23:59."   EnableClientScript="False">
</cc1:MaskedEditValidator>
```

Так вот, при отправке на сервер происходит перезагрузка страницы. А маски в текстбоксе уже нет.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что надо сделать, чтобы маска сохранилась?

Answer (score 1):

А попробуйте сделать отдельным контролом и прописать его в web.config:

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TextBoxSumma.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="Controls_TextBoxSumma" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbSumma" runat="server" Width="130px" 
    ValidationGroup="vgSumma" />
<ajaxCT:MaskedEditExtender ID="meeSumma" runat="server" Mask="999,999,999.99" MaskType="Number"
    TargetControlID="tbSumma" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="true" AutoComplete="true" CultureName="ru-RU"
    InputDirection="RightToLeft" />
<ajaxCT:MaskedEditValidator ID="mevSumma" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbSumma"
    ControlExtender="meeSumma" Display="Dynamic" TooltipMessage="Введите значение до 1 000 000 000 рублей"
    IsValidEmpty="false" EmptyValueMessage="Введите значение" InvalidValueMessage="Значение не действительно"
    MaximumValue="999999999" MaximumValueMessage="Значение слишком велико" ValidationGroup="vgSumma"/>
...

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.ComponentModel;

public partial class Controls_TextBoxSumma : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return tbSumma.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            tbSumma.Text = value;
        }
    }

    public string ValidationGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return tbSumma.ValidationGroup;
        }
        set
        {
            tbSumma.ValidationGroup = value;
        }
    }
    public Boolean IsValidEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            return mevSumma.IsValidEmpty;
        }
        set
        {
            mevSumma.IsValidEmpty = value;
        }
    }

    public Boolean AutoPostBack
    {
        get
        {
            return tbSumma.AutoPostBack;
        }
        set
        {
            tbSumma.AutoPostBack = value;
        }
    }
    public String ToolTip
    {
        get
        {
            return tbSumma.ToolTip;
        }
        set
        {
            tbSumma.ToolTip = value;
        }
    }
    public static readonly object EventCustomTextChanged = new Object();
    public event EventHandler TextChanged
    {
        add { tbSumma.TextChanged += value; }
        remove { tbSumma.TextChanged -= value; }
    }
 }
```

Конфиг...

```
    <controls>

        <add tagPrefix="udp" tagName="TextBoxSumma" src="~/Controls/TextBoxSumma.ascx"/>

      </controls>
    </pages>
  <sessionState timeout="300" />
   </system.web>
```

В коде страницы примерно так:

```
 ((Controls_TextBoxSumma)(блабалабла)).Visible = false;
```